# Login Failed Error is displaying in Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, reportviewer

I'm using Report Viewer in my website. I'm getting the following error when i view that report:

```
An error has occurred during report processing.
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
        Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

I have given the connection string in web.config file as,

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="TPSConnectionString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=***********;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Data Source=MyDataSource" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

The credentials for it are correct. I'm not able to understand why I'm getting that error. Please any one of you provide a solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the `sa` account is enabled.  Also make sure that `SQL Server Authentication` is enabled as well as `Windows`

[image]

First make sure your connection string is using the correct `sa` password.  If you do not know it, you can also try resetting the `sa` password via `sqlcmd`

Open up command prompt and type:

```
sqlcmd –S SQLSERVER\INSTANCE
```

Where `SQLSERVER\INSTANCE` is your `SQL` box and `INSTANCE` is the instance for that database.

Type:

```
sp_password @new = ’newpassword’, @loginame = ‘sa’
GO
EXIT
```

Try logging in with your new password.  Ensure the `Connection String` reflects this.

Comment: `sa` account is enabled and authentication mode is `SQl Server Authentication`

Comment: @VamsiPamula - can you login via management studio okay? With the `sa` account or any other account?

Comment: I'm logging in using `sa` account only

Comment: First try to retype your correct password in config. It could be typo. Check in management studio is it still valid.